# Cardview is not showing in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

Before I ask, I may have a strange sentence because I can not speak English well. Please acknowledge it beforehand.

I tried to show card views by putting a recycle view inside the fragment. However, the card views are not visible at all. I would appreciate it if you could tell me what the problem is.

Home.java

```java
package com.rudolphriding.giftfriend;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Home extends Fragment
{
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;
    private RecyclerAdapter adapter;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View hView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        //recyclerview
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)hView.findViewById(R.id.home_recyclerview);

        initData();

        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.scrollToPosition(0);



        return hView;
    }
/*
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        initData();
    }
*/

    private void initData()
    {
        List<RecyclerItem> items = new ArrayList<>();
        RecyclerItem[] item = new RecyclerItem[2];
        item[0] = new RecyclerItem(R.drawable.rudingworld_start1, "TEST#1", "SUBTEST#1");
        item[1] = new RecyclerItem(R.drawable.rudingworld_start2, "TEST#2", "SUBTEST#2");

        for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            items.add(item[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

RecyclerAdapter.java

```java
package com.rudolphriding.giftfriend;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.List;

public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder>
{
    Context context;
    List<RecyclerItem> items;
    int itemLayout;

    public RecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<RecyclerItem> items, int itemLayout)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
        this.itemLayout = itemLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        View v= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_trend_cardview, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    //@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        final RecyclerItem item = items.get(position);

        holder.image.setImageResource(item.getBackground());
        holder.title.setText(item.getTitle());
        holder.subtitle.setText(item.getSubtitle());

        holder.cardview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v)
                    {
                    Toast.makeText(context,item.getTitle(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
                );
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() { return this.items.size(); }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView image;
        TextView title;
        TextView subtitle;
        CardView cardview;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            image = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardview_image_title);
            title = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardview_text_title);
            subtitle = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardview_text_subtitle) ;
            cardview = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardview);
        }
    }
}
```

*There was no difference annotated or not @TargetApi

RecyclerItem.java

```java
public class RecyclerItem
{
    int background;
    String title;
    String subtitle;


    public int getBackground() { return this.background; }

    public String getTitle() { return title; }

    public String getSubtitle() { return subtitle; }



    public RecyclerItem(int background, String title, String subtitle)
    {
        this.background = background;
        this.title = title;
        this.subtitle = subtitle;
    }
}
```

fragment_home.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/home_recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

item_trend_cardview.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.rudolphriding.giftfriend.SquareCardView
        android:id="@+id/cardview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="2dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/cardview_image_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/rudingworld_start1"/>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#80000000"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="16dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/cardview_text_title"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                        android:paddingTop="8dp"
                        android:text="Title goes here"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="24sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/cardview_text_subtitle"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Subtitle here"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="14sp"/>

                </LinearLayout>


                <!--LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="8dp">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/cardview_button_01"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingRight="8dp"
                        android:background="#00000000"
                        android:text="Action1"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/cardview_button_02"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="#00000000"
                        android:text="Action2"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>


                </LinearLayout-->

            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>




    </com.rudolphriding.giftfriend.SquareCardView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

*There is customized image view to put square images in the card view.

*I also annotated the buttons because I do not know how to make them appear in the card view yet.

SquareImageView.java

```java
package com.rudolphriding.giftfriend;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class SquareImageView extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView {

    public SquareImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SquareImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) { super(context, attrs); }

    public SquareImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) { super(context, attrs, defStyle); }

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
        int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        int size = width > height ? height : width;
        setMeasuredDimension(size, size); // make it square
    }

}
```

Spent a lot of days, but I do not know what's wrong yet. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Please also post any error/warning log if generated. It is very important to know what error or warning is generated.

Comment: You don't seem to assign the data to the adapter. You generate them in `initData()`, put them in an array called `items` but don't do anything with this array. You probably want to assign the items to your adapter. Also it looks like you never actually create an adapter. You just assign the adapter (which at this point is null) to the recycler view.

Comment: @SnehPandya There was no error message. Thank you! I'll refer to the next question.

Comment: @fjc I can't understand what you are saying because I am studying, but thank you for your kind reply :)

Comment: Well please check out the answers below. They solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are not creating the adapter. Try this:

```
    private void initData()
    {
        List<RecyclerItem> items = new ArrayList<>();
        RecyclerItem[] item = new RecyclerItem[2];
        item[0] = new RecyclerItem(R.drawable.rudingworld_start1, "TEST#1", "SUBTEST#1");
        item[1] = new RecyclerItem(R.drawable.rudingworld_start2, "TEST#2", "SUBTEST#2");

        for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            items.add(item[i]);
        }
        adapter= new RecyclerAdapter(getActivity(), items, 
            R.layout.item_trend_cardview);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the friendly answer! I tried to apply the method you told me, but it still does not work. I'll try again. ;(

Comment: The rest of your code seems ok, maybe your problem is in the activity, are you adding your fragment correctly? is the fragment showing?

Comment: My thoughts exactly, you may want to run the code in debug mode with a break point in the onCreateView() of the Home fragment to see if your program gets there.

Comment: Problem solved! Custom cardview was the reason. I replace cardview to costraintlayout in item_trend_cardview and initdata showed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, you need to initialize the adapter and assign it the generated items. Right now, your adapter is never initialized and just remains `null`.

A possible solution:

```
private void initData()
    {
        // ...
        this.adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(getActivity(), items, R.layout.item_trend_cardview); 
    }
```

**Update:** Took R.layout.item_trend_cardview as the actual layout ID instead an exemplary 0 before.

Comment: Right! Thank you for your reply. But it still is not fixed. I'll try harder.